# Replace certain string in array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, replaceall

let's say I have this string array in java

```java
String[] test = {"hahaha lol", "jeng jeng jeng", "stack overflow"};
```

but now I want to replace all the whitespaces in the strings inside the array above to `%20`, to make it like this

```java
String[] test = {"hahaha%20lol", "jeng%20jeng%20jeng", "stack%20overflow"};
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Note that your question and its title diverge - your question is very specific, while the title is very general. My answer below goes into the question, not the title.

Comment: `String.replace()` ...examples to follow no doubt ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the Array and replace each entry with its encoded version.

Like so, assuming that you are actually looking for URL-compatible Strings only:

```
for (int index =0; index < test.length; index++){
  test[index] = URLEncoder.encode(test[index], "UTF-8");
}
```

To conform to current Java, you have to specify the encoding - however, it should always be `UTF-8`.

If you want a more generic version, do what everyone else suggests:

```
for (int index =0; index < test.length; index++){
    test[index] = test[index].replace(" ", "%20");
}
```

Comment: Note that, annoyingly, [`URLEncoder.encode(str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String)) is deprecated in favor of its overloaded form which takes the encoding type as a second argument (which should always be "UTF-8").

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution:

```
for (int i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
    test[i] = test[i].replaceAll(" ", "%20");
}
```

However, it looks like you're trying to escape these strings for use in a URL, in which case I suggest you look for a library which does it for you.

Comment: Look to my answer for that, it's part of the JDK.

Comment: Rush to answer a simple question and make simple mistakes :)

Comment: Also, see my comment on maerics' answer re: replace and replaceall.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`String#relaceAll(regex,replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29); untested, but this should work:

```java
for (int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
  test[i] = test[i].replaceAll(" ", "%20");
}
```

Comment: Note that `String#replace(target, replacement)` should do the trick.
`replace` does the same as `replaceAll`, but doesn't work with RegExes.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] test={"hahaha lol","jeng jeng jeng","stack overflow"};
                for (int i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
                    test[i]=test[i].replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

for each String you would do a replaceAll("\\s", "%20")

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of the Java docs... [String java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

You can do String.replace('toreplace','replacement').

Iterate through each member of the array with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) instead. Code might look something like this:

```java
String[] test = {"hahaha lol", "jeng jeng jeng", "stack overflow"};

IntStream.range(0, test.length).forEach(i ->
        // replace non-empty sequences
        // of whitespace characters
        test[i] = test[i].replaceAll("\\s+", "%20"));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
// [hahaha%20lol, jeng%20jeng%20jeng, stack%20overflow]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to replace a whole string with another in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381483/14838237)</sup>