# Add wildcards to each word in string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, wildcard

I have a Sentence

```
String query = "This is a sample Sentence"
```

I extracted all the words from it.

```
 String[] queryWords = query.split(" ");
```

... and this gives;

```
[ "This", "is", "a", "simple", "sentence"]
```

Now I want to add wildcards to each word.

```
[ "%This%" , "%is%" , "%a%" , "%simple%" , "%sentence%" ]
```

To add `%` symbol at the beginning and end of each word.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: `queryWords[i] = "%" + queryWords[i] + "%";` in a loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java replace certain string in array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005284/java-replace-certain-string-in-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over all strings in `queryWords` and replace with a new `String` that is the old `String` with the `'%'` added at the beginning and the end

```
for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; ++i) {
    queryWords[i] = '%' + queryWords[i] + '%';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `Stream`,

```
queryWords = Arrays.stream(queryWords).map(s -> "%"+s+"%").toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks. will update to this code when i upgrade to java8

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop over the array like

```
    for(int i = 0; i< test.length; i++){
        s[i] = "%" + s[i] + "%";
    }
```

http://schabby.de/java-for/

Comment: it is look in the tags =)

Comment: "for each" is not Java.

Comment: This will only change the local `s` variable, not what is in `queryWords`.

Comment: for each can be used in java.